# Not generating csv files as expected

Tags: python, csv

Here is my code snippet:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
def connection():
    import csv
    new_row = []
    flag = 15
    with open('sample_records.csv', 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            dateObject = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            minute_of_day = dateObject.minute
            minute_of_day = int(minute_of_day)
            if minute_of_day >= flag:
                file_name_of_new_csv = ("%s.csv" %
                                        dateObject.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M"))
                new_csv_writer = csv.writer(open(file_name_of_new_csv, "w"),
                                            delimiter=',')
                new_csv_writer.writerow(new_row)
                if flag + 15 == 60:
                    flag = 0
                flag = flag + 15
                new_row = []
            else:
                new_row.extend(row)

def main():
    connection()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The sample_records.csv contains:

```
2014-07-24 15:00:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:01:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:02:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:15:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:16:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:17:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:30:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:31:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:32:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:45:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:46:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 15:47:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 16:00:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 16:01:00,1,1,1,1,1001
2014-07-24 16:02:00,1,1,1,1,1001
```

Here I am trying to generate 3 csv files per hour. So 15th hour contains 3 files, but it doesn't generate the file for the 16th hour.

I am getting 15th hour csv files:

```
2014-07-24_15:15.csv
2014-07-24_15:30.csv
2014-07-24_15:45.csv
```

But I should also get:

```
2014-07-24_16:15.csv
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind `flag`? I don't understand what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: The thing is that I am generating 3 files per hour with an interval of 15 min each. Meaning 15:00, 15:01, 15:02 files belongs to 2014-07-24_15:15.csv and so on. Once this csv file is ready , the flag gets incremented by 15 for next interval that is between 15-30 which generates 014-07-24_15:30.csv and so on. This should happen for each and every hour in a day. But it is only generating for one hour only that is 15th.

Comment: You may or may not have better luck using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) instead of writing your own grouping logic.

Comment: But code seems to be work almost the way I want it to but It doesnt generate the same files for the 16th hour. Maybe I need to get the hour as well and increment it by one each time the 3 files are generated or something like that?

Comment: This may be relevant: `flag` never has a value of 0 for very long. Whenever you set it to zero, you immediately increment it to 15 right afterward. This may explain why the 16 hour records are rejected, since they all have minute values smaller than 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sample I would say you don't get `16:15` because you have no rows with time stamps `>= 15` in their minutes field...

BTW, You can replace:

```
if flag + 15 == 60:
  flag = 0
flag = flag + 15
```

with:

```
flag = (flag + 15) % 60
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a debugger and set a breakpoint at line

```
 if minute_of_day >= flag:
```

Then you can watch values of `row[0]`, `minute_of_day` and `flag`. This should help to understand what happens.